# python beautifulsoup no link when parsing 'a' tag and href

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Apologies if there is a duplicate, I searched but couldn't find an answer. 
I was writing a scraper to scrape a default directory index page served by my webserver. The html looks like this

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /Mysongs</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /Mysongs</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="Mysong1.mkv">Mysong1.mp3</a>                        10-May-2016 07:24           183019
<a href="Mysong2.mkv">Mysong2.ogg</a>                        10-May-2016 07:27           177205
```

The `href` link looks like a text only, and not a url (`<a href="Mysong2.mkv">`), but on pointing to the text, it shows the link in the browser's status bar (`http://127.0.0.1/Mysongs/Mysong2.ogg`)

I tried to extract the url using beautifulsoup, like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(sys.argv[1])
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    print link.get('href')
```

and I am not able to get the link like `http://127.0.0.1/Mysongs/Mysong2.ogg`, but only `<a href="Mysong1.mkv">Mysong1.mp3</a>                        10-May-2016 07:24`

Should I be using the `sys.argv[1]` to construct the href link like

```
print sys.argv[1] + link.get('href')
```

or is there some better way to get this?

Edit:: Current output is

```
Mysong1.mp3
Mysong2.ogg
```

Expected output:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Mysong1.mp3
http://127.0.0.1/Mysong1.0gg
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as output?

Comment: Thank you @AniMenon, I was intending to pass these urls to an external download accelerator that downloads chunks consecutively. So I was looking for urls instead of just plain text. I could create the url by concatenating the base url and the text, but I was wondering if this is the only way, and there is a pythonic way or a module support.

Comment: post expected output and current output.

Comment: Done, @AniMenon. Thank you.

Comment: @init Beautiful soup always returns whatever is in the href,  so if you want the output like that then adding the base url is your only option.

Comment: Thank you @AniMenon, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it. I was unsure whether there are any other methods that the module has, that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your only option is to add the base url. But don't add it this way:

`print sys.argv[1] + link.get('href')`

Use this:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
urljoin('http://something.com/random/abc.html', '../../music/MySong.mp3')
```

In your method, the relative paths may not be identified & handled, `urljoin` handles it.